# How to return json response as chunks in webservice response?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple `Spring` rest webservice endpoint that exposes the result of a `myqsl` query as `json`:

```
@RestController
public class DbController {
    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Map<String, Object>> query() {
        return crudRepository.queryForList(sql);
    }
}
```

Problem: for large queries returning like 500k objects (means: rows), this consumes a lot of memory.

Is there any way I could write "partial" `json` results out to the response stream?

Comment: You can think of implementing a pagination.

Comment: By partial do you mean to limit the rows that are returned or limit the columns per row?

Comment: I don't want to limit anything. I just wan to write out some kind of "partial json" response in chunks, so I don't have to serialize all rows (each a json object) at once in one go. And thus having reduced memory load.

Comment: Anyway for such large dataset you will need some limit, you can implement pagination and you will get number of rows.Then you can in JS some script where you will sent for example if you have 100 000 rows 5 requests that will return you 20 000 each

Comment: But the js client would then have to know the number of rows in advance. Which is not possible as the sql in my case always returns different number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pagination` to create a chunk of data for client per request.

You can do something like this:

Repository:

```
@Repository
    public interface SomethingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Something, Long> {
        Page<Something> findByMember_Id(Long memberId, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

SomethingPageDto:

```
public class SomethingPageDto{

    @JsonProperty("favourite_list")
    private List<SomethingDto> somethings= new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("total_pages")
    private int totalPages;

    @JsonProperty("current_page")
    private int currentPage;

    @JsonProperty("total_elements")
    private Long totalElements;

    @JsonProperty("current_page_elements")
    private int currentPageElement;
    }
```

Service:

```
@Autowired
private SomethingRepository repository;

public SomethingPageDTO getSomething(int pageNo, int pageSize, Long memberId) throws Exception {

Pageable paging = new PageRequest(pageNo, pageSize);

Page<Something> somethingPage = repository.findByMember_Id(memberId, paging);

//map EntityList to DTO

List<SomethingPageDTO > somethingDtos = new ArrayList<>();
return somethingDtos = somethingPage.getContent();
                       //somethingPage.getTotalElements();
                       //somethingPage.getTotalPages();
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some")
public class EmployeeController 
{
    @Autowired
    somethingService service;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Something>> getAll(
                        @RequestParam Integer pageNo, 
                        @RequestParam Integer pageSize,
                        @RequestParam Long memberId

    {
        List<somethingDto> list = service.getSomething(pageNo, pageSize, memberId);

        return new ResponseEntity<List<SomethingDto>>(list, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
}
```

more resources at:

https://dzone.com/articles/pagination-in-springboot-applications

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/pagination-sorting-example/

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-pagination-in-spring

Comment: But how can I client know in advance how many pages could be returned?

Comment: @membersound spring handles it itself, you just need to create a DTO that contains a list of something and other fields like totalElements and totalPages and send it to client as response.
I have added some comments in service section(under return line), and a sample somethingPageDto.

Comment: does it help you?? @membersound